# Detecting architecture in Erlang

Tags: architecture, erlang

I am writing a code to detect and execute architecture specific code in Erlang. However I am unable to get the exact syntax for same.
eg: if (x86_64) , %## execute some instruction ##%

Can someone point to the right documentation for same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
erlang:system_info(system_architecture).
```

Will return something like:

```
"x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
```

Documentation is available at http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html